# Loggingout shows Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

When I logout on the Profile Page, the website briefly shows this. But the website is working perfectly fine, this compiled with problems only shows When I logout on the Profile Page. When I logout anywhere else this doesn't happen. I've been trying to find the error since last night, please help me find the error because I'm losing my mind.

[image: pic1]

code of ProfileScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import ProfileTabs from '../components/profileComponents/ProfileTabs';
import Orders from './../components/profileComponents/Orders';
import moment from 'moment';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getUserDetails } from '../Redux/Actions/userActions';

const ProfileScreen = () => {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
  const { userInfo } = userLogin;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getUserDetails('profile'));
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div className="container mt-lg-5 mt-3">
        <div className="row align-items-start">
          <div className="col-lg-4 p-0 shadow ">
            <div className="author-card pb-0 pb-md-3">
              <div className="author-card-cover"></div>
              <div className="author-card-profile row">
                <div className="author-card-avatar col-md-5">
                  <img src="./images/user.png" alt="userprofileimage" />
                </div>
                <div className="author-card-details col-md-7">
                  <h5 className="author-card-name mb-2">
                    <strong>{userInfo.name}</strong>
                  </h5>
                  <span className="author-card-position">
                    <>Joined {moment(userInfo.createdAt).format('LL')}</>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="wizard pt-3 ">
              <div class="d-flex align-items-start">
                <div
                  class="nav align-items-start flex-column col-12 nav-pills me-3 "
                  id="v-pills-tab"
                  role="tablist"
                  aria-orientation="vertical"
                >
                  <button
                    class="nav-link active"
                    id="v-pills-home-tab"
                    data-bs-toggle="pill"
                    data-bs-target="#v-pills-home"
                    type="button"
                    role="tab"
                    aria-controls="v-pills-home"
                    aria-selected="true"
                  >
                    Profile Settings
                  </button>
                  <button
                    class="nav-link d-flex justify-content-between"
                    id="v-pills-profile-tab"
                    data-bs-toggle="pill"
                    data-bs-target="#v-pills-profile"
                    type="button"
                    role="tab"
                    aria-controls="v-pills-profile"
                    aria-selected="false"
                  >
                    Orders List
                    <span className="badge2">3</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          {/* panels */}
          <div
            class="tab-content col-lg-8 pb-5 pt-lg-0 pt-3"
            id="v-pills-tabContent"
          >
            <div
              class="tab-pane fade show active"
              id="v-pills-home"
              role="tabpanel"
              aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab"
            >
              <ProfileTabs />
            </div>
            <div
              class="tab-pane fade"
              id="v-pills-profile"
              role="tabpanel"
              aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab"
            >
              <Orders />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default ProfileScreen;
```

code of ProfileTabs.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Toast from './../LoadingError/Toast';
import Message from './../LoadingError/Error';
import Loading from './../LoadingError/Loading';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import { updateUserProfile } from '../../Redux/Actions/userActions';

const ProfileTabs = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('');
  const toastId = React.useRef(null);

  const Toastobjects = {
    pauseOnFocusLoss: false,
    draggable: false,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    autoClose: 2000,
  };

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const userDetails = useSelector((state) => state.userDetails);
  const { loading, error, user } = userDetails;

  const userUpdateProfile = useSelector((state) => state.userUpdateProfile);
  const { loading: updateLoading } = userUpdateProfile;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      setName(user.name);
      setEmail(user.email);
    }
  }, [dispatch, user]);

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      if (!toast.isActive(toastId.current)) {
        toastId.current = toast.error('Passwords Do Not Match', Toastobjects);
      }
    } else {
      dispatch(updateUserProfile({ id: user._id, name, email, password }));
      if (!toast.isActive(toastId.current)) {
        toastId.current = toast.success('Profile Updated', Toastobjects);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Toast />
      {error && <Message variant="alert-danger">{error}</Message>}
      {loading && <Loading />}
      {updateLoading && <Loading />}
      <form className="row  form-container" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <div className="form">
            <label for="account-fn">UserName</label>
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="text"
              required
              value={name}
              onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="col-md-6">
          <div className="form">
            <label for="account-email">Email Address</label>
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="email"
              required
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <div className="form">
            <label for="account-pass">New Password</label>
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="password"
              required
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <div className="form">
            <label for="account-confirm-pass">Confirm Password</label>
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="password"
              required
              value={confirmPassword}
              onChange={(e) => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Update Profile</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default ProfileTabs;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't quite figure out where the logout functionality is. But I'm assuming when a user logs out, you set the user/userInfo to undefined.

So then either here:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      setName(user.name);
      setEmail(user.email);
    }
  }, [dispatch, user]);
```

user is undefined, so then you try and set name to undefined.name which is gonna throw the error

OR

it's happening here:

```
<h5 className="author-card-name mb-2">
  <strong>{userInfo.name}</strong>
</h5>
```

for the same reason.
When a user logs out, instead of setting the user to null or undefined, instead just set it to an empty object ie: {} . Or a hackier approach might be doing the following, but then you have to make sure you're doing this everywhere where you call a property of user:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      setName((user || {}).name);
      setEmail((user || {}).email);
    }
  }, [dispatch, user]);
```

and

```
<h5 className="author-card-name mb-2">
  <strong>{(userInfo || {}).name}</strong>
</h5>
```

and that should solve it in the short term.

Comment: When logging out this function is called https://imgur.com/1sL5OGX I did the hackier approach but unfortunately the problem is still there

Comment: Yeah, based on that image its because your user is undefined but you're still trying to read properties of it.

When you say the error is still there, is it still `undefined of property('name')` or is it another error now? Because if you just fix it for .name, it will still throw other places, like: `userInfo.createdAt` and `user._id`

Comment: I've checked again and it's now undefined of property('createdAt') the problem was 
`<h5 className="author-card-name mb-2">
  <strong>{userInfo.name}</strong>
</h5>` and 
`<span className="author-card-position">
          <>Joined {moment(userInfo.createdAt).format('LL')}</>
 </span>` so I did your solution to both of them and it worked. thank you bro. I tried the solution of Sharan Balakrishnan and it worked too.

Comment: Yep, thats what I was saying above when I mentioned you need to use that solution everywhere where you call `user` or `userInfo`. However, if you just use `localstorage.setItem("userInfo", {})` instead of `localstorage.removeItem("userInfo")` it should handle it all, but you still need to handle an empty object correctly as well.

Comment: Just saw your edit that you managed to solve it. No problem, glad I could help and thanks for accepting the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're getting the desired object for **userInfo** . If yes, then for a quickfix you can do something like this

```
{userInfo ? userInfo.name : ''}
```